# Xcode Storyboard preview size classes blank

Tags: xcode, uistoryboard

I have a problem with storyboard preview. When I select a old ViewController created with a previous version of Xcode (6.0), the preview show me only the navigation bar. But, if I create a new ViewController and put inside it some elements, the preview works. The current version of Xcode is the 6.3.2.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface elements that you put inside the "old ViewController" were added under a particular size class. You are not *in* that size class with your preview, so those interface elements are not present.

Comment: Thanks, there is a solution for this?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "solution", because there's no problem. Xcode is behaving as expected. The + button and rotate-arrow buttons in the preview let you show what your interface will look like when the hardware and orientation result in a different size class. Of course, if you didn't mean to restrict your design to one size class, then that's your own fault; you should have designed your interface under w:Any h:Any, not under a specific size class.