# Xcode 7 beta 5, Swift 2: UITableViewCell's subviews are not added to the contentView at runtime

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, xcode7

Following phenomena happens when using Xcode 7 beta 5 and Swift 2:

When using a custom UICollectionViewCell that is created in the storyboard, the cell's subviews are not added to the cell's `contentView`. Thus the cell remains blank on runtime.

If I however create a custom cell class for the cell and then programmatically add the subviews to the contentView and set their `frame` the cell's content is displayed:

```
class Cell : UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        NSLog("subiews.count=%d", contentView.subviews.count) // prints "0"

        contentView.subviews.count
        contentView.addSubview(label)

        label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21)
    }
}
```

Again, without manually adding the label (that has been added in the storyboard!) and setting its frame, it would not be visible at runtime! In the storyboard the label *is* a subview of the content view. At run time it *is not*.

I cannot observe this behavior in latest Xcode 6 with Swift 1.2.

Can somebody confirm this silly behavior? And maybe provide an easier workaround?

**Edit:**
Luckily view constraints on the cell's subviews are applied after these views have been added programmatically to `contentView`. Thus at least manually setting their frames is not necessary.

Comment: I see you're ignoring auto layout here....

Comment: @TheCodingArt Auto layout just makes it unnecessary to set the views' frames. You however still need to add the views to `contentView` programmatically.

Comment: Without adding constraints in code, this will not end the way you think it will. Autolayout does not play well with just frame programming. I advice you to look up how the auto layout engine works and to inspect your view hierarchy at run time

Comment: Using Auto layout or not is not related to this problem. Please read my question again and let me know if I need to clarify.

Comment: I have a suspected feeling that you don't understand how the layout cycle works and this is leading to what you see. A simple inspection of the debug view hierarchy using the basic xcode view inspector should reveal what's going on

Comment: The debug view hierarchy exactly reveals what my post is about: the cell's content view has zero subviews. Again, this has nothing to do with auto layout.

Comment: "When using a custom UICollectionViewCell that is created in the storyboard, the cell's subviews are not added to the cell's contentView. Thus the cell remains blank on runtime" Because you designed the cell and added its subviews in some other size class? That's the usual reason why subviews from the storyboard don't appear at runtime. See my answer here, for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31119940/341994

Comment: I'm having the same problem with UICollectionViewCell in Xcode 7.3 with Swift 2.2. Everything in the content view is marked installed, though, so @Halyna Rubashko answer doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a similar question here [UITableView Empty with iOS 9 beta 5 update](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32041855/2674336)

And my answer for it https://stackoverflow.com/a/32052154/2674336

I can't say if this is a universal solution, but in the exact same scenario (tablviewcell content empty at runtime after updating to XCode 7 beta 5) this solved it for me:

I had to go through every single item inside the content view (including all constraints) and tick the checkbox "Installed" in the properties inspector. Initially only wR hR was checked.
[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this programmatically? Also what does "installed" actually do?

Comment: As far as I understand this allows you to select which form-factor you view/constraint is applicable to. RxR is iPad full screen, and first one is "applicable in any form factor". My application is iPad only, so RxR only should be (and was until beta 5) fine. As for fixing programmatically, you could probably do it for items you have outlets for in your code, but have not tried that.