# Retrieve constraint values within collection view cell?

Tags: ios, swift2, constraints, xcode7

How can I programmatically access a storyboard-set constraint on a prototype cell for a collection view?

I'm working within the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout's `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:)` method.

[image: Collection cell setup, including constraints]

Specifically, I want the aspect ratio set up for the Image View.

The cell isn't available yet at this point, and the constraint isn't present in the collection view's constraints array. (*Edit for clarification*: I can't access the cell's content, and since the constraints are associated with the cell, they're not present in the collection view's constraints array.)

I can't set an outlet, as the cell is repeating content.

Other than creating a cell or layout subclass, how can I access this constraint?

I'm using Xcode 7.3 with Swift 2.2.

Comment: "I want the aspect ratio set up for the Image View." But you know what it is. I know what it is. It's 16:9. I don't see what the issue is. "the constraint isn't present in the collection view's constraints array." No, it's in the image view's constraints array.

Comment: Yah, @matt, but if somebody comes along and changes that constraint, it won't be 16:9 anymore - and the code won't know it.

Comment: Who would this "somebody" be? No user can access the storyboard, and the programmer has direct knowledge of its contents. I really don't see that there is any problem here.

Comment: The question is how to access it, not why or should I.

Comment: You have two ways. You can access the image view and look in its constraints array, or you can use an outlet. Actually a third way would be to create this constraint itself in code.

Comment: As I noted, an outlet can't be set on repeating content. And, the cell hasn't been created yet, so I can't access the image view. Is there perhaps a connection via the storyboard object?

Comment: That makes no sense. A thing in the storyboard doesn't _exist_ until it is loaded _from_ the storyboard. When it is loaded, it _does_ exist and you _can_ have an outlet on it. People use outlets into things in a cell all the time; it's a crucial technique. How else would you access something in a cell?

Comment: Accessing an item within repeating content requires a custom class. An outlet can be connected to an item in the custom cell class. Again, as I noted in my question, I was looking for a way to avoid that. If you know a way and can give an example, please provide an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: You could give the image view a `tag`, access the image view via its `tag` instead of an outlet, and thus access its constraints. — But it is literally three lines of code to make this a custom class with an outlet, so I don't see what your objection is. You seem to think you get to make the rules for what reality is and can therefore limit what the possible answers are. You don't have that power. I'm telling you how things are. You can't wish away reality.

Comment: The image view has a tag. Again, I can't access it if I can't access the cell that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: That's right. So you have to wait until it _does_ exist. You can retrieve it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Or, you can ask the table view to dequeue one copy of the cell for you in other code, and get it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the same issue specified in this question: [Xcode 7 beta 5, Swift 2: UITableViewCell's subviews are not added to the contentView at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32027137/1107226)

The contentView's subviews aren't available unless programmatically added *in addition to* the storyboard's customization. This problem exists even with a custom cell class.

The solution in that question (making sure everything is marked as *installed* in the storyboard) didn't work for me, so, for the time being at least, I'll be using a hardcoded aspect ratio.